# How to use webworker API in angularjs..?

Tags: angularjs, web-worker

I am new to using of web worker API in angularjs, I want to know the flow sequence for the web worker in angularjs, i.e., should I write services, then use them in controller and so on.. please i want to know flow sequence...

Comment: This question feel too broad to me. Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: i want to know how we use web worker in  Angularjs

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the question is very general.

But for those, who need to implement a particular task in angular environment I can recommend plugin  https://github.com/vkiryukhin/ng-vkthread It let you easily export a function in a thread, execute it and get result in UI.

something like this:

```
/* function to execute in a thread */
function foo(n, m){
    return n + m;
}

/* create an object, which you pass to vkThread as an argument*/
var param = {
      fn: foo      // <-- function to execute
      args: [1, 2] // <-- arguments for this function
    };

/* run thread */
vkThread.exec(param).then(
   function (data) {
       console.log(data);  // <-- thread returns 3
    },
    function(err) {
        alert(err);  // <-- thread returns error message
    }

);
```

see live demo at: http://www.eslinstructor.net/ng-vkthread/demo/

contact me on github if you have any questions